# Reducing id combinations in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I have a pandas dataframe that has combinations of two id columns such as this:

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| A | D |
| A | E |
| B | C |
| B | D |
| B | E |
| C | D |
| C | E |
| D | E |
| F | H |
| I | K |
| K | J |
| G | F |
| G | H |
| I | J |

Here we have the choose 2 combinations for ABCD, FGH, IJK.

I would like to only keep the rows for the value with the most ID1's for a particular set. For ABCD this would be A, for FGH this would be G, and for IJK this would be I. Resulting in the following:

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| A | D |
| A | E |
| I | K |
| G | F |
| G | H |
| I | J |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't know in advance the groups, this could be approached as a graph problem using [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/).

You have the following graph:

[image]

What you need is to find the root of each cluster (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122390/getting-the-root-head-of-a-digraph-in-networkx-python) for the method to find roots).

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='ID1', target='ID2',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

roots = [n for n,d in G.in_degree() if d==0] 

df2 = df[df['ID1'].isin(roots)]
```

output:

```
   ID1 ID2
0    A   B
1    A   C
2    A   D
3    A   E
11   I   K
13   G   F
14   G   H
15   I   J
```

Comment: root is always the one with the most children or there may be charts where root is not the one with the most children?

Comment: @ansev as it's the root, I guess it is the parent of all, so it has the most children (per cluster), no?

Comment: I have never heard of this package, thanks for pointing me in the direction.

Comment: The point here is to know if they have to be children or children / grandchildren / ... :) But nice  as usual:) @mozway

Comment: What is nice with `networkx` (or graph theory in general), is that complex pandas transformations can sometimes be greatly simplified

Answer (score 3):

Calculate the count of unqiue values in `ID1`, then inside a list comprehension for each set calculate the index of maximum value, finally use these indices to filter the rows in dataframe

```
c = df['ID1'].value_counts()
i = [c.reindex([*s]).idxmax() for s in ['ABCB', 'FGH', 'IJK']]

df[df['ID1'].isin(i)]
```

---

```
   ID1 ID2
0    A   B
1    A   C
2    A   D
3    A   E
11   I   K
13   G   F
14   G   H
15   I   J
```

Comment: Nice one ;) but you need to have prior knowledge of the groups

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned no previous knowledge of the groups. This is similar to how I was trying but couldn't get passed that.